# Having issues with checking if function already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having issues with trying to make this query work, I keep getting errors, here is the code and after that the related error

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ConcatNames]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
BEGIN

   EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
      create function dbo.ConcatNames(@ProdId int) returns varchar(8000)
      as
      begin 
      declare @output varchar(8000)
      select @output = coalesce(@output + ', ', '') + Name
      from Reports
      where ProdID = @ProdId and Name > ''
      return @output
      end'
     PRINT N'Created function ConcatNames'
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    PRINT N'function ConcatAttributeNames Already Exists'
  END
```

Error

> Msg 119, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Must pass parameter number 2 and subsequent parameters as '@name = value'.
>   After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent parameters 
>   must be passed in the form '@name = value'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server is seeing this as one code block so "create function" is going to fail. Hence the error you get after doing what Justin suggested.

To do it this way (printing messages, and such), you have to execute the statement as you initially had it. Except you must set the text first:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ConcatAttributeNames]') AND
 type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT')) 
BEGIN 

    declare @statement nvarchar(4000)

    set @statement = N'
    create function [dbo].[ConcatAttributeNames] (@prodId int) returns varchar(8000) 
    as 
    begin  
        declare @output varchar(8000)

        select @output = coalesce(@output + '', '', '''') + AttributeName 
        from Report_Attribute 
        where ProdID = @ProdId and AttributeName > '''' 

        return @output 
    end '

    exec sp_executesql @statement

    PRINT N'Created function ConcatAttributeNames' 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    PRINT N'function ConcatAttributeNames Already Exists' 
END
```

Also, since you're passing this a statement, the single quotes must be escaped to avoid errors.

Comment: I tried this on SQLFiddle and got errors. You need to modify your code:   declare @statement nvarchar(4000)    AND why do you have ** around the declare? If you meant to bold via SO, that does not work within code blocks

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I fixed the code for future reference.